# Publish Cloud Service with Powershell - Reserved Ip Issue

Tags: .net, powershell, azure

I have a Cloud Service in Azure, and I decided to write a PowerShell script to automate build & publish for this Cloud Service. I stucked with one problem. When I'm running followingscript:

```
Set-AzureDeployment -Upgrade -Slot $slot -Package $package_url -Configuration $config -ServiceName $service -Force
```

I'm getting following error:

> Set-AzureDeployment : BadRequest: A reserved IP cannot be added,
>   removed, or changed during deplyoment update or upgrade.

I'm not trying to do anything with Reserved IP. In config file (generated by msbuild) there is a section like following:

```
<ReservedIPs>
   <ReservedIP name="MY-SERVICE-NAME-SLOT" />
</ReservedIPs>
```

I tried to remove it but it doesn't help.
If I'm deploying my service for the first time everything works like intended. I can't believe you can only release new Cloud Services but can't update with PowerShell, it would make no sense for me. There must be a way to update service with PowerShell.

Any help appreciated.

EDIT

As @Wilfried Woivré suggested I checked ReservedIPName using following commands:

```
    $deployment = Get-AzureDeployment -ServiceName $service -Slot $slot -ErrorAction silentlycontinue 
    Write-Host $deployment.Name
    Get-AzureReservedIP
```

So after executing

> Get-AzureReservedIP

I found that ReservedIPName in my config is EXACTLY THE SAME to the one which is present in deplyoment I'm trying to upgrade. So the answer is wrong.

Mr. Wilfried Woivré - in the future please test your answer before posting

Answer (score 0):

You can make an upgrade of your Cloud Services on Azure even if you have a ReservedIP. And your script seems correct.

To make this, the ReservedIP must be the same on your existing service and on your config file. 
You can check your current deployment with this command

```
Get-AzureDeployment -ServiceName $service -Slot $slot
```

And to verify your ReservedIP, you can call the method Get-AzureReservedIP, and you can see the use of each

Comment: The ReservedIp is the same in config file.